# Object in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In want to get value of `a` clicked on `href` `attr`(is an object)

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ekw0fnL9/)

**HTML**

```
<a href='#test'>Click on me</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var g = {};
    g.test = {
        title: 'my title',
        content: 'Hi,you can do it !',
    };
    $('a').click(function () {
        var request = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
        var request = eval(request);
        alert(g.request)
        console.log(g.request);
    })
})
```

Comment: I'm very confused. you want to get part of the href?

Comment: if you are trying to access the value of key referred by `request`... then member operator

Comment: There's no question in your question, nor a problem description. Also it's not clear what you want. If you've troubles with the code, please describe the problem in words, and ask a specific question. Most likely you need `g.request = request` instead of the `eval` stuff.

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Please add more detail.

Comment: the code has error ! in console of the borwser says : >test is not defined

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hcfpht8j/3/

Comment: @ArunPJohny thanks solved

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access an object inside `g` with its variable name and using the id attribute, try this :

```
$(function () {
    var g = {};
    g.test = {
        title: 'my title',
        content: 'Hi,you can do it !',
    };
    $('a').click(function () {
        var request = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
        console.log(g[request]);
    })
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ekw0fnL9/1/